# Why does Visual Studio Code use global python config despite pointing to my virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, visual-studio-code

I have a workspace folder, with a virtual environment under /venv/ I have an older version of opencv-python installed here (3.4.6.27) than what I have globally (4.4.0.46). However, despite pointing visual studio code to my venv, inspecting the version shows the higher one.

I.e., When I activate the venv in a terminal, then

```
pip list
```

I get this

```
Package       Version
------------- --------
numpy         1.19.4
opencv-python 3.4.6.27
pip           20.1.1
setuptools    47.1.0
```

But in a visual studio notebook:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution("opencv-python").version
```

provides

```
'4.4.0.46'
```

When I click to select to the interpreter, it is pointing to the *correct* path.

```
Current: ~/Desktop/workspace/venv/bin/python
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: I believe it is possible for a Jupyter notebook in VS Code to use a different interpreter than the VS Code interpreter setting. Check the Python kernel by clicking the kernel name up on the top right of the window (Look for "Python 3: Idle" or similar). Click that and make sure it is pointing at the right Python executable.

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for a Jupyter notebook in VS Code to use a different interpreter than the VS Code interpreter setting. Check the Python kernel by clicking the kernel name up on the top right of the window (Look for "Python 3: Idle" or similar). Click that and make sure it is pointing at the right Python executable.